# data from firebase not displaying in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to display student information according to the usn searched but when I click the read button the data isn't displaying. Im stuck here.Any help soon would be really helpful.

this is my firebase structure

```
"sem1Info1": {
    "users": {
      "-N6nPEDs0OEgpeESJSXl": {
        "BACKLOGS": "5",
        "CGPA": "55",
        "SGPA": "55",
        "USN": 132
      }
    }
  }
```

and this is the android studio code that would be of use

```
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    .
    private TextView retrieveTV, retrieveTV1, retrieveTV2, readBtn,enterUsn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mentor_home);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        retrieveTV = findViewById(R.id.tv_mentName);
        retrieveTV1 = findViewById(R.id.tv_studName);
        retrieveTV2 = findViewById(R.id.tv_usn);
        enterUsn=findViewById(R.id.etusername);
        readBtn = findViewById(R.id.readdataBtn);
        String usn= enterUsn.getText().toString();
        readBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                firebaseDatabase.getReference("sem1Info1").child("users").orderByChild("USN").equalTo(usn).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            
                            String spga=snapshot.child("SGPA").getValue().toString();
                            String cgpa =snapshot.child("CGPA").getValue().toString();
                            String back=snapshot.child("BACKLOGS").getValue().toString();
                            retrieveTV.setText(spga);
                            retrieveTV1.setText(cgpa);
                            retrieveTV2.setText(back);

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MentorHome.this,"ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    ;
                });
            }
        });
        
        }
}
```

Comment: Is it usn = -N6nPEDs0OEgpeESJSXl ?

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @GobuCSG No. Usn is 132

Comment: @sanjanasbharadwaj you've refer this child "-N6nPEDs0OEgpeESJSXl" then only you can fetch.. So first create another tree TREE_NAME:{"132" : "-N6nPEDs0OEgpeESJSXl"} get the value from here then, firebaseDatabase.getReference("sem1Info1").child("users").child("PASS THE VALUE"). No need orderByChild there

Comment: orderByChild() Order results by the value of a specified child key or nested child path.

Refer this : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data

Comment: how do i generate the  tree{"132" : "-N6nPEDs0OEgpeESJSXl"} dynamically everytime a user enters data ? is there a way i can make the usn as key?